# Crystal report navigation buttons not working on IE 10 and IE 11

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, crystal-reports

Crystal reports were running fine on IE 8 ~ IE 11 when deployed on development server **(Windows 7 and IIS 7.5)**, deploying this application on production server **(Windows Server 2008 r2 and IIS 7)** revels that crystal report navigation button not working on IE 10 and 11 as shown in below image.

[image]

**Things for further considerations:**

1. Initially when application deployed on development server we were getting **bobj undefined error**, we solve it by copying **aspnet_client and crystalreportviewers13** folders into our application.
2. After that crystal report **stuck on navigation** when we try to see **page 2** of reports, it was occurring on all browsers. We resolve it by moving our code from **Page_Load()** to **Page_Init()** method.

After these two steps crystal reports were tested on IE 8 ~ IE 11 using virtual environments and there were no issue but as soon as we deployed application on production server, crystal reports starts to stuck on navigation on IE 10 and IE 11.

**P.S.**

1. We are using compatibility tag in our .aspx page that tell the browsers to render report in IE 8 mode, we tried IE 7, EmulateIE8 and all other options available but none works so far.
2. Crystal reports are working fine on IE 8 and IE 9 deployed on production server.
3. Network trace reveals that on IE 10 and 11, on pressing **Next Page** button, instead of sending call to respective .aspx page,  a call is made to **"......\empty.html"**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was searching for a solution **w.r.t to IE11**, as **IE11 use Mozilla kit** so i searched the same issue with Mozilla, there came a suggestion that solve my problem.

Add the below code in the **Page directive** of your .aspx page in which you have added your **CrystalReportViewer**.

```
ClientTarget="uplevel"
```